# IIS redirect rule priority

Tags: .net, http, iis, redirect

If I'm using `httpRedirect` and `rewrite` in my Web.config file, how can I specify which rule takes precedence?

For instance, let's say I have a general catch all rule like `wildcard="*"`, but also have a `wildcard="/news" destination="/new/news"`, it seems like only the `wildcard="*"` rule is executed.

It is possible to get such behavior from Apache; I imagine there must be a way in IIS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Precedence is the same as the order they're specified in. IIS Manager has a "Move up" and "Move down" button that re-orders them for you.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^foo/?bar=123"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="foo.aspx?bar=special" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rule2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^foo/?bar=([A-z0-9]+)"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="foo.aspx?bar={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rule3" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^foo/"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="somethingElse.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Consider an incoming request for `/foo?bar=123`.

In this example, because `Rule1` is first, it means that the request will be rewritten to `foo.aspx?bar=special` instead of `foo.aspx?bar=123`, even though it simultaneously matches `Rule1`, `Rule2`, and `Rule3`.

The `stopProcessing="true"` attribute ensures that other matching rules are not executed (i.e. `Rule2` and `Rule3`).

Source: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rules_Evaluation

> Each configuration level in IIS can have zero or more rewrite rules defined. **The rules are evaluated in the same order in which they are specified**. The URL Rewrite Module processes the set of rules by using the following algorithm:
>
> 1. First, the URL is matched against the pattern of a rule. If it does not match, the URL Rewrite Module immediately stops processing that rule, and goes on to the next rule.
> 2. If a pattern matches and there are no conditions for the rule, the URL Rewrite Module performs the action specified for this rule and then goes on to the next rule, where it uses the substituted URL as an input for that rule.
> 3. If a pattern matches and there are conditions for the rule, the URL Rewrite Module evaluates the conditions. If the evaluation is successful, the specified rule action is performed, and then the rewritten URL is used as input to the subsequent rule

Comment: could you explain this in the context of the web.config file? i dont know anything about the gui.

Answer (score 0):

This saved my bacon:

[the very common mistakes when using IIS url rewrite](https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59)